# 3-2 During Sudden Death

Tags: clash-royale

Sudden Death in Clash Royale is won by destroying any of the opponent's remaining towers before they do before the time runs out. 3-3 draws have happened due to both players destroying the crown tower at the same time. Now what if one person destroyed the other opponent's tower at the same time the other player destroyed the crown tower?

Would this be a draw due to both players destroying the towers at the same time or determined as a win due to the score (3-2)?

Comment: 99% certain that would be a 3-2 win, but I've not seen it happen yet that I can recall.  I've had cases where 1 - 1 went to 2 - 2 simultaneously during Overtime before a 3 - 2 victory.

Answer (score 1):

It will be **determined as a win** due to the score (3-2), destroying tower at the same time would not result in draw. **It is based on how many tower left**.

If both players destroying crown tower at the same time, it would be (3-3).

If one destroy crown tower and another one destroy second tower, it will still be (3-2)

**(the one destroy crown tower wins)**

Comment: I think the question is asking about one player destroying a regular tower at the same time as their opponent destroys the crown tower, so it'd be a 3-2 technically, but rules of sudden death overtime might make it a draw.

Comment: my bad, wasnt clearly understand the question.